# ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error in Windows 10

Tags: oracle, errors, oracle-19c, protocol, tns

Listener and service are up and running. In SQL Plus, if I connect with no login, and execute '**conn sys/pwd@host:port/sid as sysdba**', connection is established successfully. But if I connect **/ as sysdba** or with **username  and password** , it always **throws ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error**. What are the possible reasons for this ?

Comment: `ORACLE_SID` is not set properly.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. ORACLE_SID was  not available in registry